# Bootstrap | Tab-Pane | Why is not possible to remove a border in the nav-tabs?

Tags: html, css

Why is Bootstrap ignoring my CSS styling when it comes to removing borders on the tab with the `active` attribute?

The border styling is fine on the inactive tabs but the results I'm getting are as follows

```css
.nav-tabs > li > a{
    color: #898989;
    background:linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFF, #E0DDDD)!important;
    border: 1px solid #DDD!important;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a{
    background:linear-gradient(to right, #FFF, #FFF)!important;
    border-style: solid solid none solid!important;
}
```

With this styling there should be no border on the bottom of the active tab - however, this isn't the case. If I tell the stylesheet to do something surely it should do it?

Does anyone know why my DW is ignoring `border-style` attributes?

[Result of tab-tabs immage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3SQS.png)

Comment: are you trying to remove bottom border??

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes I am for the active tab.

Comment: actually its not anchor tag's border. its nav-tabs which you are trying to remove TRY 
`.nav-tabs{border:  none !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try simply this ?

```
border: none;
```

And eventually, check in the property inspector if you are writing it in the good target in your css (and at the good line)

Answer (score 0):

Please write down this code in your CSS to remove border-bottom.

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a{border-bottom: none !important;}
```

Comment: Right, I have tried ever possible CSS border attribute combination, I just cannot get this to work! I will stat screaming momentarily.

Comment: Then please check where is active class add. Because I'm sure that it's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this It would help full-on active tab

```
.nav-tabs > li > a.active{
background:linear-gradient(to right, #FFF, #FFF)!important;
border-style: solid solid none solid!important;}
```